# Having trouble with collisionBitMask

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am suffering trying to wrack my head around this. I created another object with a category called ContactEnemyCategory and I want it to never collide with anything so I set the collisionBitMask to 0 and yet my Player Character is able to move it instead of just passing through it. It seems like a minor problem but in all honesty its just plain stressful. Any advice would be great.

**My Object**

```
contactLines = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"contact-Lines"];
contactLines.hidden = NO;
contactLines.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
contactLines.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:contactLines.size];
contactLines.position = CGPointMake(variaPlatform.position.x, variaPlatform.position.y + 30);
contactLines.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = fContactEnemyCategory;
contactLines.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = fEnemyCategory;
contactLines.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
[self addChild:contactLines];
```

**My Player**

```
_Hero = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:i1];
_Hero.name = @"Hero";
_Hero.zPosition = 2;
_Hero.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_Hero.size];
_Hero.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = fPlayerCategory | fEnemyCategory;
_Hero.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = fPlatformCategory | fEnemyCategory | fScoreCategory | fMainPlatformCategory |fPitOfCertainDoomCategory;
_Hero.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = fEnemyCategory | fPlatformCategory | fMainPlatformCategory;
_Hero.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
_Hero.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
_Hero.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
_Hero.physicsBody.friction = 0.3;
_Hero.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.7;
_Hero.physicsBody.allowsRotation = false;
_Hero.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
_Hero.position = CGPointMake(_Hero.position.x - 253, _Hero.position.y + 50);
[self addChild:_Hero];
```

**Their Respective Categories**

```
static const uint32_t fPlayerCategory = 0x1 << 0;

static const uint32_t fContactEnemyCategory = 0x1 << 6;
```

Comment: your player is in the same category as the enemy's contact mask (fEnemyCategory)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I feel really stupid -.- But no matter, the day is saved thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

I came across an issue similar to what you're facing some weeks ago.
Try setting up the physicsBody only **after** you have added the node as a child. Do this for every node you are working with that has a physicsBody.

Comment: Sadly, I still have the problem, and doing that brings up an enormous amount of other object bugs. Thanks though.